# Extract href from Beautiful soup tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
>>> type(col)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
>>> col
<td><a href="/english/js/au/">Detail</a></td>
```

Could someone help me to cleanly extract in python href as a string from the above data? I wan to get the path "/english/js/au/" as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
href = col.find('a')['href']

print(href)
```

Output:

```
/english/js/au/
```